# CSS: background-image: url with absolute path to another disk partition

Tags: css

I want to write some stylesheet and use some backgrounds in larger project, but I don't know path where the graphics will be in future in the project. So I want to only prepare it, and paths will be replaced then.
I don't want to move graphics or stylesheets. Project is on C: using xampp and graphics on D: **Question is how can I import the graphics?**
I tried something like

```
    background: url("file://localhost/D:/brig/task/image.png");    
    background: url("file://D:/brig/task/image.png");    
    background: url("D://brig/task/image.png");
```

Can I use absolute path like this??

Comment: I believe this only works on the partition you installed your web server was installed on. I may be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest you to use a **WYSIWYG** editor like dreamweaver, visual studio or any for instance.

Then make a project folder with the name `brig` and put all the relevant directories, images, etc inside it relevantly. Then when you open your HTML or css in the editor, select your main project and then when you put the images inside your HTML or CSS via `src` or `url` respectively, it will automatically make it relative and fetch it from that place where you have originally stored in your project.

**For instance,**

```
background: url("../task/image.png");
```

This `../` means a relative path for one level up directories. So in future, when you put your graphic files on the same path, this will fetch the images via a relative path as mentioned.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your css is able to get pictures as long the path is still working just by navigating with ../../../etc. It should work with other partitions on the server as good as normal url paths from web. If the partition is not on your server, just make a folder at your webroot. It's not advisable to outsorce too much  of your website.

Comment: I know that, but it doesn't work, there is 403.
I wanted to use only for development till I will know the project structure. I use other solution, e.g. symlink

Answer (score -1):

Users can't access your file system, so css doesn't work with it. If you want to use the graphics from you d: you need to  move them to the c: in the folder of your site. It can be in a subfolder.

Comment: I know, I wanted to use only for development till I will know the project structure. I use other solution, e.g. symlink